# Phpunit `markTestIncomplete` prints I when message provided

Tags: php, phpunit

Pretty simple Test case

```
final class ContactApiCorsTest extends TestCase {
  public function testGetOptionsRoute(): void {
    $this->markTestIncomplete("NOT COMPLETE");
  }
}
```

I then run this with `./src/public/vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap ./src/public/vendor/autoload.php src/tests`

Expecting to see the message `NOT COMPLETE` but getting and I output below.

```
PHPUnit 8.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
I                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
"Time: 1.14 seconds, Memory: 4.00 MB
OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Incomplete: 1.
```

How can I get PHPUnit to show the provided message?

Comment: Have you tried the [`--verbose` flag](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html)?

Comment: @GregSchmidt nailed it. I knew it had to be something like this.